# SQL Insert Based on Variables

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2014

I need to work out how to do the following.

I have two columns.

One is the Transaction Reference which is a unique number in my example I have 4,5,6.

The other is an Analysis Code 9 field. This will only ever be A, O or N.

[image]

When an Analysis 9 Code does not exist in this case O and A are missing I need to create a row per Transaction Reference - this is because I then need to use a combination of those to output a file in SSIS and the customer requires a blank file even if say Analysis Code O is not available.

So I would I would expect 6 rows created in this example.
A O for batch 4,5,6. 
A A for batch 4,5,6.

Comment: Is there any SQL you have already tried? Do these fields come from the same table?

Comment: I would want the SQL to do...I've tried a few things but nothing works. They are in the same table

Comment: when you say "when an Analysis 9 Code does not exist" do you mean, when it does not exist for a particular Transaction Reference number? Or a record does exist but the Analysis9Code = N? Your wording is confusing me a bit. Do you always want an A and O for each trans ref number?

Comment: I would always want an A and an O per Transaction Reference. So if my example only had a Transaction Reference of say 4,5,6 and 4,5 had N but 6 had only O. For 4 and 5 I would want  a O and A produced. For 6 and N and A.

Comment: Please read [this](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question. It's helpful to tag database questions with both the appropriate software (MySQL, Oracle, DB2, ...) and version, e.g. `sql-server-2014`. Differences in syntax and features often affect the answers. Note that `tsql` narrows the choices, but does not specify the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You basically want to find all the distinct transaction references and cross them with all possible codes. You then need to filter this to find out the missing pairs.

The LEFT JOIN at the end will do the filtering for you.

```
CREATE TABLE [#trans]
(
  [Transaction Reference] int,
  [Analysis 9 Code] char(1)
)

CREATE TABLE [#codes]
(
  [Code] char(1)
)

-- Create a table with all potential code values

INSERT INTO [#codes] ([Code]) VALUES ('A')
INSERT INTO [#codes] ([Code]) VALUES ('N')
INSERT INTO [#codes] ([Code]) VALUES ('O')

-- Insert your dummy data

INSERT INTO [#trans] ([Transaction Reference], [Analysis 9 Code]) VALUES (6, 'N')
INSERT INTO [#trans] ([Transaction Reference], [Analysis 9 Code]) VALUES (6, 'N')
INSERT INTO [#trans] ([Transaction Reference], [Analysis 9 Code]) VALUES (4, 'N')
INSERT INTO [#trans] ([Transaction Reference], [Analysis 9 Code]) VALUES (4, 'N')
INSERT INTO [#trans] ([Transaction Reference], [Analysis 9 Code]) VALUES (5, 'N')
INSERT INTO [#trans] ([Transaction Reference], [Analysis 9 Code]) VALUES (6, 'N')

SELECT [ExistingRefs].[Transaction Reference] AS [Transaction Reference],
       [#codes].[Code] AS [Analysis 9 Code]
 FROM 
    (
      SELECT DISTINCT([Transaction Reference]) [Transaction Reference] FROM [#trans]
    ) [ExistingRefs]
CROSS JOIN [#codes]
 LEFT JOIN [#trans] ON [ExistingRefs].[Transaction Reference] = [#trans].[Transaction Reference]
                   AND [#codes].[Code] = [#trans].[Analysis 9 Code]
    WHERE [#trans].[Analysis 9 Code] IS NULL


DROP TABLE [#trans]
DROP TABLE [#codes]
```

Comment: Perfect !! Exactly what I needed. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below.

```
select distinct t.[Transaction Reference],x.code from #trans t 
cross apply(select distinct code from #codes c inner join #trans tt on c.Code<>tt.[Analysis 9 Code])x
order by t.[Transaction Reference]
```

Thanks